# How to get baseUrl in Yii2 advanced app after Url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, yii2-advanced-app, base-url

I have used Yii2 advanced application. i rewrite url in frontend and backend.
After rewrite Frontend url is

```
localhost:83/Working-copy/mySite/
```

And For Backend

```
 localhost:83/Working-copy/mySite/admin
```

Now i want to get base url like

/Working-copy/mySite/

But i don't get it properly

I have tried following ways,

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@web') // ans= /Working-copy/mySite/admin
echo Yii::getAlias('@backend') // ans= /var/www/Working-copy/mySite/backend 
echo Yii::getAlias('@webroot') // ans= /var/www/Working-copy/mySite/backend
echo Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl // ans= /Working-copy/mySite/admin
echo Yii::$app->getBasePath(false) // ans= /var/www/Working-copy/mySite/backend
echo Yii::$app->homeUrl // ans = /Working-copy/mySite/admin/
```

In some url i get `/var/www/` and in some url get `/admin/`.

i only want my project name. 
any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create components into common folder.
2. Add Request.php

   ```
   namespace common\components;


   class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
       public $web;
       public $adminUrl;

       public function getBaseUrl(){
           return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
       }

       public function getActualBaseUrl(){
           return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl());
       }

       public function resolvePathInfo(){
           if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
               return "";
           }else{
               return parent::resolvePathInfo();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use Yii::$app->request->getActualBaseUrl().